# How to use the password_reset hook to validate new password and display error

Tags: hooks, errors

When a user resets their password via the link in the password reset email, I know I can use the `password_reset` hook to get the user object and the new password. I want to validate the new password to ensure that the strength requirements are met, but I'm not sure on how to generate the error messages so that they display above the form.

When I did this on the profile page via the `user_profile_update_errors` hook, I had a `WP_Error` I could add to, but not with this hook.

What would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using hook the `validate_password_reset` to validate password. 
Following code can be used to validate alphanumeric password.

```
    add_action('validate_password_reset','wdm_validate_password_reset',10,2);
    function wdm_validate_password_reset( $errors, $user)
    {
        $exp = '/^(?=.*\d)((?=.*[a-z])|(?=.*[A-Z])).{6,32}$/';

        if(strlen($_POST['pass1'])<6 || !preg_match($exp, $_POST['pass1']) )
               $errors->add( 'error',  'Password must be alphanumeric and contain minimum 6 characters.','');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this, first you will have to dequeue `'wc-password-strength-meter'` script and then use `'validate_password_reset'` hook to apply custom validation.

Following code can be used to validate minimum 8 characters and maximum 20, and must contain at least one capital letter, number and special character.

Dequeue script using `'wp_print_scripts'` hook

Custom Validation using `'validate_password_reset'` hook

```
function geek_wc_remove_password_strength(){
  if ( wp_script_is( 'wc-password-strength-meter', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'wc-password-strength-meter' );
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'geek_wc_remove_password_strength', 100 );

add_action('validate_password_reset','geek_validate_password_reset',10,2);
function geek_validate_password_reset($errors, $user){
  $exp = '/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@$!%*#?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*#?&]{8,20}$/';
  if(strlen($_POST['password_1'])<8 || !preg_match($exp, $_POST['password_1']) ){
    $errors->add( 'error',  'Hint: Password length must be minimum 8 characters and maximum 20, and must contain at least one capital letter, number and punctuation mark.','');
  }     
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure If I understood your question, but [here's the plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-strong-passwords/)  that forces user to input strong password.

Comment: The plugin you mentioned only enforces this on the profile page, not the password reset page.

Comment: Have you checked the plugin file on github ?  https://github.com/gyrus/Force-Strong-Passwords/blob/master/slt-force-strong-passwords.php
read from line 120

Comment: The thing is, I found a way to enforce the requirements server-side, I just don't know enough about WordPress and how to use WP_Error to display corresponding errors on the page.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written so far?